man no longer works in Cygwin
I have cygwin version 3.4.10-1.x86_64 installed on my windows 7 machine.  Until recently I could call man on any topic, e.g. $ man man; $man ls, etc. and the relevant man page would be displayed.  I then ran setup-x86.exe and noticed that in the View section of the select packages screen there was a dropdown named "Unneeded".  Possibly foolishly, I selected these and then next and let the package manager go to work.  Now I get no output whatsoever.  As far as I can tell all other applications I have installed and use work as I expect.
I tried calling $ man  -> no output; expected usage message
I tried calling $ man man -> no output; expected display of information about man pages
I tried calling $ man ls -> no output; expected display of information about ls command
I tried reinstalling man-pages-linux.
At the end of the install I get the message below:

Post install script errors:
These do not mean that affected packages will fail to function
properly, but please check
Package: 0/Perpetual /var/log/setup.log.full and report any problems.
0p_texlive_prep.dash exit code 127
Package: _/Unknown package
texlive-collection-basic.sh exit code 127
texlive-collection-latex.sh exit code 127
texlive-collection-latexextra.sh exit code 127

I can see I have man.exe, mandb.exe, cygman-2-12-1.dll, cygmandb-2-12-1.dll in /bin.
I can see I have man1 ... man8 folders in /usr/share/man
The man.n.gz files are within the above folders.
I have man-pages-6.8.pdf in /usr/share/doc

did you try:
cygcheck man

it may produce a message to help

Since posting my question my laptop failed to boot stopping with message "Windows updates 35% complete".  I was forced to recover from my backup drive.  After doing this although I lost some work it restored my system to a point in time were evidently my Cygwin files were such that man works.
